# HTML custom Font on Bootstrap wont work

Tags: html, css, fonts, twitter-bootstrap-3

So i've been in this problem for a very long time, posted a question but decided to delete it since im already using bootstrap.. now heres the thing, when i try to debug the page, my main.css and bootstrap.css got loaded but my custom fonts didn't.. im at a lost right now why my font won't be loaded.. here is the sample code..

**main.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Arvo';
    url("../fonts/custom/Arvo-Regular.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-style: normal; 
}
```

**for boostrap.css**
 - i've customized it on their site, to have my custom font included
[image]

**then on my index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

then for my Chrome Debugger, 
[image]

im currently at a lost really, cuz it won't loaded my font... and i don't know how, have read some threads but they all point me to the above modification which won't load my font

UPDATES

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: under what circumstances do you think anyone can actually read these screen captures?

Comment: ok sorry for that, i've updated my SS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have any content that actually uses the custom font. From the screen shots, it appears you're using the sans serif family as the base font family, and the first font in that stack is Helvetica Neue. If you're testing on a Mac or on another system which has Helvetica Neue installed, then the browser will never try to load the second font in your stack (which is your custom font).

**Update:**

Your syntax is wrong. You need to set the `src` property:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Arvo';
    src: url("../fonts/custom/Arvo-Regular.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-style: normal; 
}
```

Comment: ahhh i see so i have to make it the first one?

Comment: A font stack is a list of acceptable fonts in priority order. If the browser finds Helvetica Neue, it doesn't have to try any other fonts in the stack.

Comment: ok ok, tried ur way, but i think it loaded the san serif, the last one on stack, refer to my updated SS

Comment: damn man u got it.. tried this one the other day i didn't work.. that's why i've been tinkering around :( but yeah thanks man